# CUDA pow function with integer arguments

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I'm new in CUDA, and cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to calculate the distance of object it has id in array, axis x in array and axis y in array to find neighbors for each object

```
__global__ 
void dist(int *id_d, int *x_d, int *y_d, 
              int *dist_dev, int dimBlock, int i)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

    while(idx < dimBlock){
        int i;
        for(i= 0; i< dimBlock; i++){
            if (idx == i)continue;
            dist_dev[idx] = pow(x_d[idx] - x_d[i], 2) + pow(y_d[idx] - y_d[i], 2); // error here
        }
    }
}
```

Is `pow` not defined in kernel code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that while `pow` is defined in the CUDA math API (see [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_1g6d36757715384dc18e0483aa1f04f6c7)), it is not template specialised for integer arguments, ie. there is no version like this:

```
__device__ ​ int pow ( int  x, int  y )
```

This is why you are getting an error. You will need to explicitly cast the base argument to a floating point type like this:

```
dist_dev[idx] = pow((double)(x_d[idx] - x_d[i]), 2.0) + 
                    pow((double)(y_d[idx] - y_d[i]), 2.0);
```

Having said that, using double precision floating point exponential in your example for a integer square will be poor from an efficiency point of view. It would be preferable to perform the calculation using integer multiplication instead:

```
int dx = x_d[idx] - x_d[i];
int dy = y_d[idx] - y_d[i];
dist_dev[idx] = (dx * dx) + (dy * dy);
```

Comment: dist_dev[idx] = ((x_d[idx] - x_d[i]) * (x_d[idx] - x_d[i])) + ((y_d[idx] - y_d[i]) * (y_d[idx] - y_d[i]));

Comment: @Alamin: That is identical to the last code snippet in my answer. Were you trying to make a point  of some kind?